# How to send contour (cv.MatVector) to the server

Tags: javascript, opencv

I'm following the procedure given [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/daa/tutorial_js_contours_begin.html) to get and draw the contour. Now I want to send the data to server (probably as a List if List of integer or in json format ). The problem is that the `findcontour` store the contour in `cv.MatVector`. So, my question is how to convert the data in proper format to be sent to the server. (For sending data I'll be using `ajax` query )

Comment: A contour is just a list of points. It can be converted into a text string (which will have to be decoded later). Can you convert it to a text string and send it that way?